# React Router navigates to root for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

When I try and load localhost:3000/login in an application built with react-router-dom, it redirects to / for no apparent reason. No Redirect elements are being rendered, and no error messages appear after navigating to /login. I'm having trouble even figuring out how I would add logging for error messages. Adding a redirect to what renders in the / route does work, but this will cause problems answering a callback from an authorization API.

Code:

[image: App.js]

[image: Login.js]

Console Output:

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text and not as images. And can you provide a minimal [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Are you hosting your app somewhere and trying to navigate directly to a nested path? You may need to update your .htaccess to "capture" the requests for nested paths and load from your app running in the root directory (i.e. where the app is running).

Comment: @DrewReese I'm running the create-react-app dev server. It knows how to handle client side routing. That's why I don't 404 when I navigate to /login.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan I will set one of those up. I didn't know about that service. I don't know if the issue will reproduce, though, as the app server may be different than create-react-app

Comment: The issue appears to be with the mechanism that create-react-app uses to force the app to reload on changes. Using a Rest client to visit /login loads index.html correctly, but using console.log() has shown that <App /> doesn't load before the page is redirect to /.

Comment: Update: The issue is not present in Google Chrome. There is a bug with the development server which effects firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable your Ad blocker.

UBlock Origin can cause this issue. Don't know about other blockers, because I haven't tested them.